# Regex : Catastrophic backtracking when processing large string

Tags: php, regex

I need help for optimizing my regex for processing URL BBCode Tag. The regex is to check that URL tag has valid pattern and NOT containing whitelist protocol

```
#(\[url=(?:&quot;|"|\'|)(((((?!https|http|ftp|mailto).)*):(//)?)([^\[\]]*))(?:&quot;|"|\'|)\])(.*)(\[/url\])#siU
```

Regex will ignore :

- [url="www.example.com"]example[/url]
- [url="https://example.com"]example[/url]
- [url="http://example.com"]example[/url]
- [url="ftp://example.com"]example[/url]
- [url="mailto:mail@example.com"]example[/url]

And match when :

- [url="ymsgr://example.com"]example[/url]
- [url="anyprotocol://example.com"]example[/url]

It's run well and has no issue, until user create string data with more than 10000 char length, that will make **Catastrophic backtracking**

[Regex101 Reference Link](https://regex101.com/r/Zlj1jS/3)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a slightly optimized version:

```
(?:\[url=(?:&quot;|"|\'|)(?:(?:(?:(?:(?!https?|ftp|mailto).)*):(?://)?)(?:(?!"|"|&quote;).)++)(?:&quot;|"|\'|)\])(?:(?!\[/url\]).)++(?:\[/url\])
```

The main optimizations here are:

- changed most of the capture groups into non-capture groups `(?:)`
- changed .* expressions no tempered greedy tokens/excludes `(?:(?!).)`
- added some possessive quantifiers `++`
- (switching from protocol blacklist to a whitelist would also help a lot)

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/nVD6cG/2)

<sup>If you are going to use this pattern often it might be worth to mention the `S`|Study [PHP regex flag](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php). Guessing from the description, it should not be useful but might be still worth the trial. I have not tested it.</sup>

[Sample Code](https://ideone.com/oa2NTr)

---

Regarding your updated sample: It's probably best to do this in a two step process: first, extract the URL meta tags with a much simpler regex, e.g.

[`\[url=.*\[/url\]`](https://regex101.com/r/LlYvUl/1)

then, use your original regex or the one above to verify the input format.

Comment: Thanks for your response, yes it's faster than my regex when get url link. But there is still miss understanding there

I update my case in https://regex101.com/r/Zlj1jS/3

The long string not inside in URL tag, but in whole string variable